# How to handle concurrent sql updates, given database structure can change at runtime

Tags: java, mysql, sql, concurrency

I am developing spring mvc application

For now I am using **innodb mysql** but I have to develop the application to support other databases also.

Can any one please suggest me how to handle concurrent sql update on single record.

Suppose two users are trying to update same record then how to handle such scenario.

Note: My database structure is dependent on some configuration (It can change at runtime) and my spring controller is singleton in nature.

Thanks.

Update:
Just for reference I am going to implement version like https://stackoverflow.com/a/3618445/3898076).

Comment: If you use JPA, you can use Pessimistic or Optimistic Lock. [See Here](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/lock)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You are trying to say that I can use JPA and create entities which represent my tables and then query using those entities. Is my understanding correct. If yes then I have mentioned in the question that my database structure can change at runtime, can you please tell me how can I handle such changes using entities.

Comment: What does "can change at runtime" mean? Modifying the schema for applications at runtime is generally a terrible idea...

Comment: I am aware that it is not good to change the schema at runtime. But my requirement is that based on some configurations i have to generate tables. Schema change is not quite often..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transactions are the way to go when it comes to concurrent sql updates, in spring you can use a transaction manager.

As for the database structure, as far as I know MySql does not support transactions for DDL commands, that is if you change the structure concurrently with updating, you're likely to run into problems.

To handle multiple users working on the same data, you need to implement a manual "lock" or "version" field on the table to keep track of last updates.

Comment: I have less idea about transactions in spring. But can you please tell me, suppose two users have loaded same record on edit screen and both users updates some fields of the record with the gape of 5 sec. Then will `transaction stop/throw any exception` in such scenario?

Comment: No. 
And there's no database transaction system that can help you with that - keeping a db transaction opened and waiting for user input is insane. 
You'll have to do it manually in this case, using a "lock" or "version" field on that table.

Comment: Thanks for replying. but how can a lock be useful in such scenario? I have read for version but it is quite an effort for me to rewrite the queries with version field. So, if the there is no other way to achieve this then I will have to rewrite my code with version.

Comment: Either that, or accept that the second user will overwrite first user's changes

Comment: Thanks for helping. For now, I am going to implement version field in my code (like http://stackoverflow.com/a/3618445/3898076). Can you please update your answer that suggest for version along with transaction manager, so that I can accept it.