# Hibernate best pratices for fetching entities

Tags: java, database, hibernate, sql-update, fetch

1) When fetching entities from hibernate i always close the session after fetching, and often i need to fetch same entities but at different times (different sessions)

And then i need to perform some operations on the fetched entities, and there i get some problems when it comes to updating, since i perform different operations on different entities (which are exactly the same in the database)

Is there any good pratices to avoid such problem ?

2)- When updating entities from a software which is working in a network, often 2 different computers does some different operations on same entities (same in the database), but when updating, everything will be corrupted.

For example, let consider the fact of updating the quantity of a product after a sale. After a sale the quantity of the product should be less than it was, but once 2 different computers does a sale on pre-fetched product, they will surely be a wrong value in the database as i'm updating the product using jpa update() function.

Is there any good pratices also for such problems ?

Thanks and sorry if it's too abstract and unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up by updating entities using native HQL queries (for the ones who would face the same issue) then fetching again the entities (peforming a select query again) on update finished.

Answer (score 0):

On 1), you shouldn't to that without expecting concurrency problems on updating the entity informations.

On 2), you can use two strategies to deal with: **Optimistic Lock** or **Pessimistic Lock**. The Hibernate support [both strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3618445/2387977).

There is no [right answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/133933/172464) for your question. But if would like only to prevent the problem, the Optimistic Lock seems a good solution. When two computers try to update the field, the last to write the quantity on database will receive an error and the transaction will rollback.

Comment: I ended up by executing native HQL queries without using update() function... and refreshing (fetching entities again) on update performed, what do you think about it ?